# OnChanged () being called when i navigate back from a screen?

Tags: java, android

i'm facing an issue with back. i'm using java with live data. and when i navigate fragment A to Fragment B it's working. but when i navigate back from B to A then observer still called again. Can anyone help on this in JAVA.

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask a good question** carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Therefore, please provide more information and your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because LiveData was not meant to handle one-time events.

You have multiple options:

1. SingleLiveData

SingleLiveData as was introduced in Google Android Sample is a LiveData that sends an update only once.

[SingleLiveData](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

2. **EventWrapper** (If you're going to stick with LiveData for event handling I recommend this one)

```
FragmentAViewModel {
    val navigateLiveData = MutableLiveData<EventWrapper<Unit>>()
}
```

This great [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) showcases the **EventWrpper** and Single LiveData

3. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)